# Connecting printer with android tablet

Tags: android

I need to connect printer with android based tablet using usb and i need to print from my android application using usb printer.My tablet has two usb port . how can i connect it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is no normal way by which we can connect the android tablet to a USB printer, if the printer is a WiFi supporting one then there are numerous apps through which we can print.
eg:(http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/print-android-phone-printershare/)

For experiment ready guys follow this link : http://www.tombom.co.uk/blog/?p=124

Comment: Many newer Android devices have USB-host capable hardware, and USB Host APIs available to 3rd party developers.  That means that if there is sufficient low-level USB protocol information available about a printer, developing a means to print to it from Android will actually be possible.

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking to print to a big desktop printer or a receipt printer?

If you're looking for a receipt printer, Star Micronics has an Android SDK that you can freely download here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx.

It covers USB printing. The printer can be connected directly to a tablet with USB ports. Your tablet needs to have Android V3.1 or higher for direct USB connection with a printer.

This SDK has a really nice sample app that lets you test and customize a lot of printer functions to see them in action. Each function is documented in the source code. The commands and their parameters are also available in the app itself as a quick on screen reference which is convenient. On top of all that, it's well documented.

Comment: Is there anything for 'big desktop printer'? I am looking for USB solution, not Wifi or USB.

Comment: Nice demo, but i want to print full text file with printer. so please suggest me that how to make this one in this demo...